# How to refer to a variable inside quotes

Tags: python, database, import, export

I am trying to make a call to an API via XMLRPC to request info on a product.

I have a session variable which contains the session key after I login.

I have to pass my call to the procedure I want as a parameter to another call, at least this is the only way I have found for it to work.

For example:

```
import xmlrpc.client
svc = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('https://example.com/api/xmlrpc/')
session = svc.login('apiuser', 'apikey')
temp = svc.call(session, 'catalog_category.tree')
print (temp)
```

This works fine.

What I am trying to do now:

```
import xmlrpc.client
svc = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('https://example.com/api/xmlrpc/')
session = svc.login('apiuser', 'apikey')
temp = svc.call(session, "catalog_product.info(session, 'CM-RC658')")
```

Obviously this is incorrect. My issue is I am not sure how to pass the session variable to the catalog_product.info procedure, which is a string parameter to the svc.call method.

Comment: Is `session` a string then?

Comment: @gilch sorry should have said, but yes a string resembling an md5 hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an f-string.

```
temp = svc.call(session, f"catalog_product.info({session!r}, 'CM-RC658')")
```

The proxy object doesn't have a set API, but depends on the service you are using. Some of them will support introspection to tell you how to use them. Try

```
print(svc.system.listMethods())
```

to see a listing of the available methods for that API.

Once you know the name of the one you want, try

```
print(svc.system.methodSignature(foo))
```

Where `foo` is the method name (try as a string). This should tell you the valid argument signature for that method. You can also try.

```
print(svc.system.methodHelp(foo))
```

Which might give more details on how the method works. These system methods names are standard, but not all APIs have them.

---

If the above introspection methods don't work, you'll have to carefully read the documentation and experiment. I don't know your API, but I can try to guess a couple of other forms that might work. Try

```
temp = svc.call(session, "catalog_product.info", session, 'CM-RC658')
```

and

```
temp = svc.catalog_product.info(session, 'CM-RC658')
```

Comment: I don't know if this is working or not as I get "Invalid API Path" as a response with what I am trying to do. "catalog_product.info" only takes a session ID and a product number as a response so I'm not sure why it is failing.

Comment: @JakeRankin try the introspection system methods.

Comment: Not familiar with that but will look into it! Thank you.

Comment: THank you for expanding your answer! When I call listmethods I get "['system.listMethods', 'system.methodHelp', 'system.methodSignature', 'system.multicall', 'handlePhpError', 'startSession', 'endSession', 'login', 'call', 'multiCall', 'resources', 'resourceFaults', 'globalFaults']" in return. MethodHelp just gives a useless text description. I can retrieve a list of methods via SOAP and the WSDL, but I'm not sure how to use those methods via XMLRPC.

Comment: @JakeRankin `methodSignature` should show you what arguments the method named accepts.

Comment: It seems some methods are returned via Soap v2 in the WSDL, different from the methods returned via XMLRPC and soapv1. catalog_category.tree is only returned via soapv2 wsdl but I can call from xmlrpc. However when I call via xmlrpc with print(svc.system.methodSignature(catalog_category.tree)) it says name nto defined. Really confused what is going on here.

Comment: I can use introspection methods but they don't return the same methods available via soapv2 wsdl, even though I can call some of those methods. Although even doing print(svc.system.methodSignature(call)) results in an error.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the session variable using any string parsing such as `.format`:

```
temp = svc.call(session, "catalog_product.info({}, 'CM-RC658')".format(session))
```

Comment: I don't know if this is working or not as I get "Invalid API Path" as a response with what I am trying to do. "catalog_product.info" only takes a session ID and a product number as a response so I'm not sure why it is failing.

Comment: If you want to be sure, just print the value of your session and check the info.

Comment: However, as I see, it seems that your problem comes from URL path, the one that setup the `svc` variable @JakeRankin

Comment: with my URL path I can login and get a session ID, and when I do "temp = svc.call(session, 'catalog_category.tree')" it returns the catalog category tree, a lot of data. I'm just not sure how to call methods other than catalog_category.tree which have parameters.

Comment: The only way to help you with this, would be to check the API from the website you're calling, to ensure you're making the right call, to the right endpoint, and with the right arguments.

Comment: I feel like I shouldn't need to make a call just to make a call, but haven't found an alternative. Including session twice seems like it should not be necessary.